# No such host found connecting spring boot app with elasticsearch service

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am using Rest high-level client of elasticsearch to connect with elasticsearch service but I am getting below error. While connecting with localhost it's working fine.

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8080
elasticsearch.host=https://d9bc7cbca5ec49ea96a6ea683f70caca.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com
elasticsearch.port=9243
elasticsearch.username=elastic
elasticsearch.password=xxxxxxxx
```

**Elasticsearch config file**

```
package com.ElasticSearchCrud.ElasticSearchCrud;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfig {
    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public RestHighLevelClient restClient() {

        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password));

        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port))
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));

        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
        return client;
    }
}
```

**Java service**

```
 @DeleteMapping("/DeleteDocumentById")
    public String deleteProfileDocument(@RequestParam String IndexName, String Id) throws Exception {
        return service.deleteProfileDocument(IndexName, Id);
    }
```

**Error**

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-01-22T13:10:02.371+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No such host is known (https://d9bc7cbca5ec49ea96a6ea683f70caca.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com)",
    "trace": "java.io.IOException: No such host is known (https://d9bc7cbca5ec49ea96a6ea683f70caca.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com)\r\n\tat org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClient.java:964)\r\n\tat org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:233)\r\n\tat org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1448)\r\n\tat org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1418)\r\n\tat org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1388)\r\n\tat org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.delete(RestHighLevelClient.java:906)\r\n\tat com.ElasticSearchCrud.ElasticSearchCrud.EmployeeService.deleteProfileDocument(EmployeeService.java:67)\r\n\tat com.ElasticSearchCrud.ElasticSearchCrud.CrudController.deleteProfileDocument(CrudController.java:39)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:931)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:666)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)\r\nCaused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (https://d9bc7cbca5ec49ea96a6ea683f70caca.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com)\r\n\tat java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:930)\r\n\tat java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1499)\r\n\tat java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:849)\r\n\tat java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1489)\r\n\tat java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1348)\r\n\tat java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1282)\r\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)\r\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalAddressResolver.resolveRemoteAddress(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:664)\r\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalAddressResolver.resolveRemoteAddress(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:635)\r\n\tat org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.processPendingRequest(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:474)\r\n\tat org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.lease(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:280)\r\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:295)\r\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.requestConnection(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:377)\r\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.start(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:129)\r\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient.execute(InternalHttpAsyncClient.java:141)\r\n\tat org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequestAsync(RestClient.java:537)\r\n\tat org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequestAsyncNoCatch(RestClient.java:520)\r\n\tat org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:232)\r\n\t... 60 more\r\n",
    "path": "/DeleteDocumentById"
}
```

Could anyone please help me out to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove "https://" part from *elasticsearch.host* property and build the RestClient including protocol parameter:

```
RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(elasticsearchHost, elasticsearchPort, "https"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove **"https://"** (start of url)  and **":443"** (end of url), if necessary.

**Wrong:**

```
elasticsearch.host=https://d9bc7cbca5ec49ea96a6ea683f70caca.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:443
```

**Correct:**

```
elasticsearch.host=d9bc7cbca5ec49ea96a6ea683f70caca.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com
```

At HttpHost instance, you put these parametrs:

```
new HttpHost(elasticsearchHost, elasticsearchPort, "https")
```